# Can't stream a socket connection in VPC

Tags: node.js, sockets, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

in the AWS EC2 Ireland region there is only the option of using VPC. However, I can't figure out how to stream data through a socket connection with another server outside of AWS. The server I am trying to connect to has a firewall where they only allow connections from a specific IP addresses. I am using an Elastic IP for this, but it isn't working.

Specifically, I am trying to use NodeJS to stream data with something like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var socket = net.connect(options, function(){...});
socket.pipe(...)
```

I am able to do this the same way in the N. Virginia region using classic EC2 (i.e. not a VPC), but I can't figure out how to get this to work with VPC. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to define "it isn't working" a little more clearly.  You must be getting some kind of error, at least a timeout error or something.  There's nothing intrinsic to VPC that would make this different, but the easiest approach would be to try connecting to something *you control, first* instead of something somebody else controls, so you have more visibility into what's happening, such as, your source IP is not what you think it is, or you've inadvertently disabled outbound traffic on ephemeral ports.

Comment: Thanks, it is just hanging.  It doesn't seem to be getting through the firewall.  Good suggestion to try connecting to something I control first - I will try this